# I'm unable to access my Prefect 2 server remotely

Tags: python, docker, prefect

I'm trying to set-up a Prefect 2 docker container but I can't access the running server instance from outside.

I'm 100% sure this is a Prefect problem because I tested everything with netcat and curl to see if I could send a GET request locally and if I could send and receive packets from inside the container.

I've seen on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258098/cant-access-prefect-server-remotely) that you could solve this issue by adding a `--expose` flag but it has since been removed.

[image: list of available flags]

Is there an option somewhere in the config to allow other IPs?

Comment: I'm running Prefect vesion 2.10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will want to set the `PREFECT_API_URL`. See the [docs here](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/settings/?h=set#prefect_api_url).

You probably want to add that setting in your [Prefect Profile](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/settings/?h=set#configuration-profiles).

Comment: It doesn’t work, even after setting PREFECT_API_SERVER_HOST